# Python Selenium ChromeDriver Not Reachable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So I'm unable to figure out why I am getting this exception. When I run the chromedriver alone I get:

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3) on port 9515

When I try to run it from a file I get:

> WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.15.322448
>   (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3),platform=Linux
>   3.13.0-52-generic x86_64)

The code:

```
if self.proxy:
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server=http://user:password@proxy.com:8080")
    self.webdriver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/google-chrome', chrome_options=chrome_options)
else:
    self.webdriver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/google-chrome')
```

I'm running it without the proxy. If I don't supply the path, for some reason it won't be able to find the chrome binary. Not sure where I should go from here.

Answer (score 0):

The path you need to specify in the [first positional or `executable_path` keyword argument](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver) is a **path to the chromedriver, not the chrome itself**:

```
self.webdriver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

If `chromedriver` is in [`$PATH`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) - you don't need to specify the path at all - this is usually the case.

Comment: Hrm, makes sense. I had some issues with my paths. I fixed it up and am able to fire it up without even specifying a path now. But I still get the same error, sadly ( whether I specify the path or not ).

Comment: @user3084860 yeah, you are right, `chrome not reachable` is related to smth else. There are number of reasons according to what I've googled. Can you check if you get the same error instantiating chrome as just `self.webdriver = webdriver.Chrome()`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

download the [chrome driver](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.15/) and use this code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\chromedriver.exe")
```