# WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler, selenium-chromedriver

I use **[Selenium Python](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)**, 
when I run my crawler I got this error

```
WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248304,platform=Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64)
```

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30223988/python-selenium-chromedriver-not-reachable)

I downloaded chromedriver (binary) and I copy/paste it to `/usr/bin`
I tried by

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver')
```

but I have the same error

Comment: does this happen to you when using Firefox?

Comment: @YuZhang i can run Firefox by : driver = webdriver.Firefox()

Comment: In case you're running in docker: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364012/webdriver-exception-chrome-not-reachable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364012/webdriver-exception-chrome-not-reachable)

Answer (score 1):

In your protractor.configuration file, if you have the following:

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
      'binary': 'path/to/chromedriver.exe';
    }   },
```

Then please remove that binary and instead point to the chromdriver like this:

```
//protractor.conf.js
chromeDriver: "C:/path/to/chromedriver.exe",
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {

    }
  },
```

Notice how I removed the 'binary' argument from the capabilities and added the "chromedriver:" attribute.

That worked for me in removing that annoying error that says "

```
    UnknownError: chrome not reachable
        28-Jul-2016 10:16:57      
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.19.346078 (6f1f0cde889532d48ce8242342d0b84f94b114a1),
platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64)
 (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Lastly makes sure you update both chromedriver and seleniumServer like this:

> webdriver-manager update

OR 
Run this command below to update to a SPECIFIC chromedriver version i.e v2.24 as of 10/04/2016:

> webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.24

if it says that the command is not recognized, then add it to your PATH in windows environment variable. The webdriver-manager generally sits in the Protractor folder which you can get with npm install protractor

Comment: Where is that protractor.configuration file is exactly?