# get the page source using selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Im scrapping some website and and its working dynamically. Im going to all the pages in a website and meanwhile i want all the page source data of all pages in a list.
This is my code move to all the pages and get their page source. But nothing is printing or returning at the end of the function.
I did this for other website its worked, but not here.
Please help me out of this.
Thank you

```
def get_html(driver):
    output = []
    keep_going = True
    while keep_going:
        # Pull page HTML
        try:
            output.append(driver.page_source)
        except TimeoutException:
            pass
        try:
            # Check to see if a "next page" link exists
            keep_going = driver.find_element_by_class_name(
                'next ').is_displayed()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            keep_going = False
        if keep_going == True:
            try:
                driver.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                    (By.CLASS_NAME, 'next '))).click()
                time.sleep(3)
            except TimeoutException:
                keep_going = False
        else:
            keep_going = False
    print(str(len(output)))
    return (output)

raw_data = get_html(driver)
print(str(len(raw_data)) listing found")
```

This is the error output im getting.

```
> Entering search term number 1 out of 1 Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File "E:/Harshitha/python learning/python/New/rough1.py",
> line 114, in <module>
>     raw_data = get_html(driver)   File "E:/Harshitha/python learning/python/New/rough1.py", line 65, in get_html
>     output = (driver.page_source).encode('utf-8')   File "C:\Users\Harshitha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 670, in page_source
>     return self.execute(Command.GET_PAGE_SOURCE)['value']   File "C:\Users\Harshitha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 312, in execute
>     self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\Harshitha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
> line 237, in check_response
>     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not
> reachable   (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.132)   (Driver info:
> chromedriver=2.34.522940
> (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87af1),platform=Windows NT
> 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38439199/4055021)

Answer (score 1):

I use the `page_source`function:

```
driver.page_source;
```

Comment: Its a python code and its throwing an error as                               
"  'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'get_source'  "

Comment: Try driver.get_source with out ()

Comment: I change the function on python is page_source

Comment: Even i used page_source only,  but the result is not returning from the function. I used this for 5-6 websites it worked for some 3 websites but not others, i dont know why.....

Comment: Maybe this encode to utf-8 is the problem `output = (driver.page_source).encode('utf-8') `. could you try yo encode with unicode?